# 3 - bit Counter (repeat after each 6 clocks)

Tags: digital-logic, counter

I have tried to make a counter which counts until six clock cycles and then repeats.
And would like to know whether I have done all right and the counter works correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSxvt8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Want to know if it works ? Simulate it !
Either with Circuitlab (link under your picture above), no idea if that would actually work, never tried it.
Or use a program called "qucs" see: http://qucs.sourceforge.net/ .
Learning to use a simulator is an essential skill any electrical (design) engineer must master. It's not that hard.

Comment: I don't have the material.

Comment: You can download it for free ! Let me tell you, when I was a boy (in the 1980s) I could only dream of just downloading a free circuit simulator that actually works. It's so much easier these days. Enjoy that is my advise :-)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Have fun!

Comment: This circuit is not correct. First you need to label your outputs, otherwise we can't check for correctness (Q0, Q1, Q2). Let's take FF3: If it stores zero -> `Q=0` and `/Q=1`. So T3 (T of FF3) is `1`. In the next cycle it inverts Q to `1` and `/Q=0`. So T3 becomes `0`. FF3 will never toggle again, because there is no other way to drive T3.

Comment: Are you counting 0-5, 0-6, 1-6, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but not close. At a start, FF1, which I presume represents your lsb, should have its input tied to a logic high. I suspect that you intended FF3 to be the lsb, and that you have confused T flip-flops with D flip-flops. Try replacing your FFs with D-types.

Comment: Actually there were only D-flip-flops on the instruction I have followed, but I have chosen T-flip-flops because I found D flip-flops without their inverse Q' in the simulator.

Comment: Then add an inverter to the Q output to get a Q' output. And for heaven's sake, learn the difference between T and D flip-flops!

Comment: I did invert them. And Thank you for correcting me.